# Airport Shuttle

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

A shuttle transfers passengers from 5:30 to 22:30, on a route between an airport and 3 hotels. The shuttle departs the airport every hour on the hour and drops off passengers at the hotels always in the same order (airport->Sheraton->Hilton->Carlson) and with fixed travel times between station pairs:

```
Airport - Sheraton : 21 min
Sheraton - Hilton  : 5 min
Hilton - Carlson   : 4 min
Carlson - Airport  : 30 min
```

On Wednesday Eddie got on a shuttle from his hotel to the airport exactly 2 hours before his flight. To Eddie’s surprise, the ride to the airport took 8 minutes less than it took on the previous Thursday when he stayed at that same hotel and had to catch a 13:30 flight.

What time was Eddie’s flight on Wednesday?

Hint 1:

> Note that the "same order" of stations refers only to **dropping off** passengers at the hotels.

Comment: How is that possible? You said the ride takes exactly the same time to get from his hotel to the airport each time.

Comment: What is a round hour?  Does it mean on the hour?

Comment: @LeppyR64 yes, on X:00

Comment: @QuestionAsker it doesn't say that. Rather that the time between specific station pairs is the same.

Comment: Unless if I'm missing something, isn't that the same thing?

Comment: @QuestionAsker I think this might be better classified as a lateral thinking question.

Comment: Notice that we're not given any information about when Eddie departed for his flight last Thursday, so the departure time of either shuttle might be relevant to explaining why there was a 5-minute difference in the shuttle time.

Comment: @QuestionAsker I'm afraid you are missing something, that's directly connected to the solution.

Comment: @JoeZ. it accidentally said 5 minutes less. the correct number is 8 minutes less, fixed it now.

Comment: How long does the bus stop at each stop?

Comment: @2012rcampion zero time, for the purpose of this puzzle.

Comment: @GuyZ. that opens up the possibility hinted at in the other answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bus actually travels both ways on the path between the airport and the hotels — the route is 30 minutes there and 30 minutes back for a reason. However, when it leaves Carlson, it never drops anyone off until it reaches the airport.

The normal schedule looks like this:

```
Airport    :00  (dropoff and pickup)
Sheraton   :21  (dropoff and pickup)
Hilton     :26  (dropoff and pickup)
Carlson    :30  (dropoff and pickup)
Airport   1:00
```

But since the shuttle bus starts at 05:30 every morning, it actually starts off at the Carlson hotel. On the first trip of the day only (from 05:30 to 06:00), it picks people up from all three hotels on the way to the airport, dropping them all off once it arrives, as a service to the early riders from the other two hotels who shouldn't have to wait a whole hour more for the shuttle bus.

```
Carlson    :30  (pickup only)
Hilton     :34  (pickup only)
Sheraton   :39  (pickup only)
Airport   1:00  (dropoff and pickup)
```

So if Eddie lives at the Hilton, he will board the bus at 05:34 and arrive at 06:00, for a trip time of 26 minutes. Since he boarded the bus at 05:34, his plane is scheduled to leave at **07:34**.

But for subsequent trips, it will go from Carlson straight to the airport without any more pickup stops because it has already visited the hotels a short time earlier, and visits each location every hour on the specified minutes. So if Eddie was catching a 13:30 flight, he'd have to board the bus at 11:26 to arrive at 12:00, for a trip time of 34 minutes, which is 8 minutes more than if he had boarded the first bus of the day as above.

Comment: And the last trip of the day would be from 22:00 to 22:30, dropping people off at the hotels only, and not picking anybody up.

Comment: interesting actually very good haha I like it